# Psuedo selector :hover but only when a DIV has a specific class

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-events, pseudo-class

I have the following code that's triggered on the `mouseover` event of a `DIV`:

```
if(!$this.hasClass('ready')) 
{   if($this.hasClass('activated'))
    {
        $this.removeClass('activated');
    }
    $this.addClass('ready');
}
```

There's more code, but it follows basically the same conceptual pattern as above. I check the existence of a class, and only when that class is there, then I add or remove other classes. This happens at `mouseover`, and something else happens at `mouseout`. So someone suggested I just use CSS and `:hover`. But I have two different types of `DIV`, one type contains text and hence the class 'textBox' and the other contains images, and hence the class 'imgBox'.

I want to do something like:

```
div.imgBox .ready:hover
{ /* some style */ }

div.textBox .ready:hover
{ /* some style */ }
```

And so if the mouse hovers over the `div`s while they *don't* have the class `.ready`, then nothing should happen. Is this possible? I'm only trying to switch to CSS to speed up the user interaction on my page, because sometimes the mouse gets stuck while leaving or entering a `div`, and I think it might be because of this class-changing jQuery. Am I right?

### Edit

I forgot to add an important part of the question - what about nested elements?
What I mean is, I have a `div` that becomes resizable on `hover`, and when that happens, I want the previously transparent resize handles to get a colored background.

```
<div class='imgbox'>
<div class='ui-resizable-se'></div>
...
</div>
```

So what I mean is something conceptually like:

```
.imgbox:hover{ .ui-resizable-se { /*some style */ } }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you add your markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both the type and the ready classes are on the same `div`, you need to get rid of the space between the two classes:

```
div.imgBox.ready:hover
{ /* some style */ }

div.textBox.ready:hover
{ /* some style */ }
```

If you need to style nested elements simply append those, *with* a space, after the `:hover` part:

```
div.imgBox.ready:hover .ui-resizable-se
{ /* some style */ }
```

Comment: I have a question. If I apply this CSS, is it more efficient/faster than doing the same via jQuery?

Comment: Yes, it is. CSS is always faster.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add or remove classes with CSS. You can only add or remove styles depending on CSS properties. So, if you want to modify the appearance of some `div` at mouseover, you must explicitly specify the styles.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that on the hover definition:

```
$('div.ready').hover() {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

That way *only* those divs who have the ready class will have a hover event. Otherwise, nothing will happen